# How to extract data from a table using an additional query from another table?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables `feature_status` and`city_feature`:

```
CREATE TABLE feature_status
(
    feature text PRIMARY KEY,
    status  BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE city_feature
(
    feature text REFERENCES feature_status (feature) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    city_id bigint REFERENCES city (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

So i need to fetch all data from table `feature_status` where if `status` in `feature_status` is `NULL` then i need to check if `city_id` exists in mapping `city_feature` IF exists `THEN` set `status` `TRUE` or else `FALSE`. I'm not totally sure do i need use `LEFT OUTTER JOIN` and i don't know how to do it if it really possible?

for example:

```
feature | status        feature | city
----------------  AND   ---------------
'FOO'   | TRUE          'CLUB'  | '001'
'BAR'   | FALSE         'LODZ'  | '001'
'LODZ'  | NULL          'LODZ'  | '002'
'CLUB'  | NULL
```

so for select query for city = '002' result will be this:

```
    feature | status    
    ---------------- 
    'FOO'   | TRUE   
    'BAR'   | FALSE 
    'LODZ'  | TRUE
    'CLUB'  | FALSE
```

Comment: why is the status of  `CLUB` False in the output ? `CLUB` does have a `city_id` in city_feature.

Comment: bad example sorry i made mistake i will rewrite it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with `Left Join`

```
select a.feature, coalesce(a.status, b.feature is not null) status
from feature_status a 
     left join city_feature b on a.feature = b.feature and city_id = 2
```